# Get current logged in user in Spring AOP using Spring Webflux

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-aop, spring-reactive

I am using Spring Webflux with Kotlin Coroutine and Spring AOP. I have simple Advice which is like this.

```
@Around("@annotation(LogAccess)")
public Object logErrorAccess(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

    MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    Method method = methodSignature.getMethod();
    LogAccess logAccess = method.getAnnotation(LogAccess.class);

    try {
        var result = joinPoint.proceed();
        // Get the current user and user id and log
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Get the current user and user id and log
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I tried to use this.

```
ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(ct -> ct.getAuthentication().getPrincipal());
```

But I am getting `null`. I am using JWT for Auth, However in my controller I can access that information like this.

```
@GetMapping("/profile")
suspend fun profile(authentication: Authentication): Response
```

Is there any way to get this info in Advice somehow.

Comment: You can use reactor context (https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context)


Meaning the context you want to access is attached to your Mono or Flux.
I am on the same pb right now.
Maybe by accessing the Mono or Flux in parameter ?

Comment: ReactiveSecurityContextHolder use the Context API behind. Can you provide how you are using ReactiveSecurityContextHolder in the advice ?

Comment: do you have an answer for this?